# Many to many relationship react-admin

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

Im trying to show in a `Datagrid` a `Field` that is in a many to many relationship (intermediate table).

I have these tables:

group - group_subject - subject

- A group can have many subjects
- A subject can be connected with many Groups

> group_subject also has attributes like rubrics and schedule

It's a many to many relationship. I would like to show in the `<Resource>` `group` all the subjects that a group is connected to.

Using something like the `<SingleFieldList>`:
[as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3In65.png)

I'm using `react-admin`. Is there a way to get values in this relationship?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to *hide* that intermediate table from react-admin. It's a good thing to hide this implementation detail anyway IMO. Users of your API shouldn't be aware of it.

- from the `groups` resource perspective, a group has many subjects, each subject having a `group_id` and you API should allow to retrieve subjects by this `group_id` field
- from the `subjects` resource perspective, a subject has many groups, each group having a `subject_id` and you API should allow to retrieve groups by this `subject_id` field

Comment: I found on Github that `<ReferenceManyField>` and `<ReferenceArrayField>` is intended for this use case, but I cant make them work. For example my REST API (OData) endpoint `User(1)/Roles` returns roles assigned under User with Id = 1. If I use those components I can specify `reference` and `target` props but I am not able to navigate React Admin to endpoint like `User(1)/Roles`. Users and Roles are in many-to-many relationship and I have pivot (intermediate) table to store relations for that, so I dont exactly have references in `User` or `Role` table. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Actually, even though your answer doesn't answer the question it is not a bad idea and it seems the best option, given 'react-admin' can't handle it. I just designed the backend dto to return results directly attached instead of the intermediary endpoint. Did the same for update to take directly IDs of end model. This way for the front end, no intermediate tables exist and works as expected with minimal beckend work.

Comment: react-admin does handle it, for a price: Their Enterprise support includes a ManyToMany component: https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/modules/ra-relationships#referencemanytomanyfield -- I was searching here to figure out if someone had created a free variant. No luck so far.

Comment: Have you made any progress in your search @SomeCallMeTim? It's weird to me that this is not something of a dealbreaker for using react admin in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, that project ended up moving to a different platform and I didn't need to solve the problem at all any more. To be honest, though, paying for components shouldn't be considered an automatic deal-breaker. Developers gotta eat.

Answer (score 0):

From `react-admin` documentation `<ReferenceField>` can be used for this purpose. More on [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html). Maybe this is a pretty late answer, but I think this can be helpful for others.

Comment: The free tools for react-admin only handle Many->One and One->Many. They've put the Many-to-Many support behind a paywall: https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/modules/ra-relationships#referencemanytomanyfield